# C# Editing text in binding textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, windows-phone

I have the following code:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="/Images/check.png" Stretch="Fill" 
    Visibility="{Binding Checked}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding Uid}" Tap="RemindName_Tap" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Padding="10,2,0,0" Foreground="White" Height="40"  Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="24" 
    Width="365"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Something here" Tag="{Binding Uid}"/>
```

How to edit text in second textblock?

There has to be "time" in the appropriate format. That I have in isolated storage, but I have to be properly formatted.

Comment: Your question makes little sense to me... how do you data bind a string property to a `TextBlock.Text` property?? Really? Where's the problem?

Comment: Using c# I want to change the value of the second textblock. I dom't know how to do it.

Comment: @GoOx you need a twoway binding: {Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: Why can you not use the same method that you use to change the first `TextBlock.Text` property?

Comment: Now I have a whole list in the xml file and immediately I add it to the listbox. I have this idea that I would do something like this: foreach(Class item in list) {code} and the next change what i need and I will add to the listbox. This is a good solution?